# Why is $\langle\alpha x+y, \alpha x+y\rangle = |\alpha|^2\|x\|^2 + (\alpha\langle x, y\rangle + \bar{\alpha}\langle y, x\rangle) + \|y\|^2.$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inner-products

I have a proof that proves the Cauchy Schwarz inequality. I am at the stage where I am trying to show the inequality holds for when $\langle x, y\rangle \neq 0$ and $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent.

> For $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, $\alpha x +y \neq 0$, then
>
> $$0 < \|\alpha x+y\|^2 = \langle\alpha x+y, \alpha x+y\rangle = |\alpha|^2\|x\|^2 + (\alpha\langle x, y\rangle + \bar{\alpha}\langle y, x\rangle) + \|y\|^2.$$

How do we see that $\langle\alpha x+y, \alpha x+y\rangle = |\alpha|^2\|x\|^2 + (\alpha\langle x, y\rangle + \bar{\alpha}\langle y, x\rangle) + \|y\|^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a complex inner product in complex linear in the first argument (i.e. $\langle kv, w\rangle = k\langle v, w\rangle$), complex antilinear in the second argument (i.e. $\langle v, kw\rangle = \bar{k}\langle v, w\rangle$), and $\langle v, v\rangle = \|v\|^2$. With all of this in mind, we have

\begin{align*}
\langle\alpha x + y, \alpha x + y\rangle &= \langle\alpha x, \alpha x\rangle + \langle\alpha x, y\rangle + \langle y, \alpha x\rangle + \langle y, y\rangle\\
&= \alpha\bar{\alpha}\langle x, x\rangle + \alpha\langle x, y\rangle + \bar{\alpha}\langle y, x\rangle + \|y\|^2\\
&=|\alpha|^2\|x\|^2 + \alpha\langle x, y\rangle + \bar{\alpha}\langle y, x\rangle + \|y\|^2.
\end{align*}